# Transparent image over a video

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, media-player

Im using C# in VS2017 and have a MediaPLayer control to play a video.

I want to overlap some part of the video with a PNG image with transparency. In VS2017, elements are transparent to their parent. So, to make the image be transparent to the video I have to set it as child of the video.

But if I do that, the image doesn't display at all. Video is always refreshing and overlapping the image (even if I do a constant BringToFront in the image).

So, I change the Parent of the image to the form. Now the image displays, but through it's transparency I see the form's background, not the video.

Target platform is Windows. Is there any solution for this?

Also I moved from VLC Control to MediaPlayer. Performance is better but this issue continues. And I can't move to WPF.

Comment: How about using 2 panels, one on top of the other. The back panel has the video. The front panel has a transparent background and the png. Haven't tested it but just a thought.

Comment: I've just tried. Doens't work.

Comment: You can host WPF controls in WinForms. See your Toolbox -> WPF Interoperability -> [Element Host](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx). Overlaying an image to a WMP control while a video is playing is... improbable. Unless you want to play with DirectShow, but you'ld have to work with Data Streams...